# What is the best way to access iOS filesystem from an app?

Tags: ios, ipad, cryptography

I'll be working on a cryptographic app for iPad soon. Along to some other features, I'd like to be able to get documents within the iPad's file system to work with them.

So far, I haven't experimented with that, but I've seen apps such as pdf readers that don't share their files with other apps and can't reach files belonging to other apps. Is it possible -and legal- to reach all the files in the iPad from an app?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The applications you are seeing performing "file sharing functions," are just sending URLs to other apps.  It is not possible to retrieve any document you haven't been handed to either by the user through iTunes, or through a custom URL scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This is not possible unless you Jailbreak your device.  All applications are sandboxed and can only access files they are in the their individual sandbox.

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend another schema for obtaining files? Something like a client-server model?

Comment: Either way - there isn't an easy way to get files from other applications.